# XAML-Binding to Control in ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, binding

The ViewModel class:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string SomeText { get{...} set {...}}
    public AnyNonMVVMControl MyControl { get {...} set {...}}
    ...
}
```

The Window XAML:

```
<Grid>
...
<TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeText}" />
<??? Content="{Binding MyControl}" /> <!-- how to bind MyControl to the View? -->
...
</Grid>
```

Assign the Model

```
...
window.DataContext = new MyViewModel(...);
...
```

I have a Control, which isn´t designed for MVVM. Rendering and Data are strongly coupled (bad design solution). I have this control in my viewmodel and want to bind it to my window. But I don´t want to add the Control directly in the XAML, because this control contains also business logic and data -> I need to access it in the viewmodel for performing actions.

So, how to "add" the control via Bindings to the window?

Comment: Exposing a control from a view model is not MVVM, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ContentPresenter` or `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyControl}" />
```